# which is the best way to making web service using java or j2ee for android client?

Tags: java, android, web-services

i want to make web service for my android client basically i m android developer and i have no idea to develop a web service

please send a good tutorials link so that i can start with basic.

Comment: Why must it be a web service?

Comment: i think it's easy to manage and update databases

Comment: The reason to why I asked, was that it could possibly be easier to use google app engine and normal html/servlets/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm guessing you want to create the webservice in Java yeh?  I'd use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) (which is the reference implementation of JAX-RS).

The website above has pretty good documentation on how to use Jersey, but in short you can do the following:

Download the jars and add them to your project or add the following to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey</artifactId>
  <version>0.8-ea</version>
</dependency>
```

Annotate your Resource pojo class with [@Path](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e110) to specify the url for that resource.

Annotate your methods with [@Path](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e110) to specify more fine grained urls.

Annotate your method arguments with [@PathParam](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e110) if you want to get access to the parts of the url path designated for that resource method.

Annotate your methods with [@GET, @POST, @PUT or @DELETE](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e135) to specify which HTTP method they will respond to.

Annotate your methods with [@Produces](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e150)/[@Consumes](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e182) to specify what MIME type the resource accepts or produces.

An example of a class that might use some or all of these methods is as follows:

```
@Path("/users/{username}")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
      ...
    }
}
```

That's the basics.  It's as easy as that.  Knock yourself out.

Comment: No probs.  Feel free to mark the above as the answer if/when you are happy that it answers your question ;)

Comment: can u providing link for helloword project for eclipse?